# Example of recursion using Python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def f(n):
 
 if(n<=1):
  return 1
 f(n-1)
 print (n)
 f(n-1)
  
f(4)
```

The output is:`2324232`
I didn't understand its working.
Can anybody help me please....

Comment: There's no [tag:for-loop] nor any [tag:c] code in the question — why did you add those tags?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there are no data structures, either. Unless you count the call stack but I wouldn't.

Comment: The best way to understand, how this recursion works, is by debugging step by step using any IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step:

- You call it with 4

  - Recurses to 3

    - f(2)

      - f(1) -> returns
    - prints(2)
    - f(2)

      - f(1) -> returns
  - prints(3)
  - Recurses to 3

    - f(2)

      - f(1) -> returns
    - prints(2)
    - f(2)

      - f(1) -> returns
- prints(4)
- whole tree again